# UDF Accept different types of inputs

Tags: function, input, sum, range, variant

How to allow this simple math UDF to accept as input a selected range of 3 cells as well as selecting cells separated by commas, same as how the standard SUM() function works in Excel.

```
Function SurfaceAreaCuboid(l, w, h) As Variant
    SurfaceAreaCuboid = 2 * ((l * h) + (l * w) + (w * h))
End Function
```